# stateful never[] array is still being able to assign data

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-typescript

I know that when passing an empty array to useState hook we should also provide the proper type, otherwise typescript would infer never[].

The following is something I did before knowing that and by my surprise is working:

It's a component intended to fetch some data, that data is of type any and will be stored in loadedUsers, which has a type of never[].

```
const AllUsers: FC<AllUsersProps> = () => {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  const [loadedUsers, setLoadedUsers] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    UserService.getAllUsers()
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        console.log("users after retrieving data", data);

        setIsLoading(false);
        setLoadedUsers(data);
      });
  }, []);
```

Then I use loadedUsers to render a simple view

```
if (isLoading) {
    return (
      <section>
        <p>Loading users</p>
      </section>
    );
  }

  return (
    <div className="row">
      <div className="col">
        <h3>Users table</h3>
        <UserTable users={loadedUsers} />
      </div>
      <div className="col">
        <h3>Find user by id</h3>
        <UserSearch />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Why am I not getting any errors during compilation? even in vscode there is no warning message

Comment: Can you check the type definition of `data` when you set it in `setLoadedUsers(data)`? Try setting an explicit type

Comment: Yes! at that point data is an infered type of any (data is an array of objects actually) I tried setting explicitly the correct type that is User[ ] and now I can see the error of "User[] is not assignable to type never[]"

Comment: Now my only question would be why data when has an any type is able to be assigned to a never[ ] array

Comment: `any` means anything, which includes `never[]`